# print row prime number in recursion def python

Tags: python, function, recursion

Hi guys can u help i want to make number list prime in python but with no for loop do or while in inside or outside only with recursive function

this is mycode with def recursion, can u guys help me change to print 2-limit in def recursive ?

```
def is_prime(n, div=2):

if div> n/2.0: return True

if n% div == 0:
    return False
else:
    div+=1
    return is_prime(n,div)
```

but this will need for outside def to print all number 2-100

```
#The program:
for i in range(2,100,1):
if is_prime(i):
    print(i)
```

how to change the for in outside def, with just

```
limit = int(input("input limit prime = )
print(is_prime(limit,2)
```

what i mean is, how to print 2-limit with recursion in def without loop for,while outside def. im confuse how to make recursive function from it
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you goal is to perform recusion on your function without an outside loop, this is a solution...

```
def is_prime(n, max_n, div=2):

    if n> max_n: return False

    if div > n / 2.0:
        print(n)
        return is_prime(n+1,max_n)

    if n % div == 0:
        return is_prime(n + 1, max_n)
    else:

        return is_prime(n , max_n,div+1)# forgot to increment div and not increment n so we can runit through the function again

is_prime(2, 100)
```

Comment: Thanks Dunksi u made my day, hope u have a great day ! Thankyou :)

Comment: oh hi dunski i have a question i think i might be wrong with def, on another my python i code with
def prime(n,j):
    if(n<2):
        return False
    if(j==n):
        return True
    if(n%j==0):
        return False
    return prime(n,j+1)

print(prime(n,2))

that to find prime number, can u modified for me to print list like def 
with def i code (is_prime) to print all the prime list, i think thats its odd number not prime because when i print it show "9" thats should be odd not prime right ?

Comment: Ur def is_prime that u give to me it print a number "9" too. its odd not prime what should i have to edited it ?

Comment: So sorry. you are right. I have updated the answer. It works now